# Include SVG xml in Jade template

Tags: javascript, svg, pug

Is it possible to create a Jade mixin, which reads a file from the file system, and echoes it into the rendered HTML?

I tried this...

```
mixin svg(file)
    - var fs = require("fs");
    - var xml = fs.readFileSync(file)
    div= xml
```

... but it fails because `require` does not exist.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I guess there are two ways to achieve this. Latter one just shows the straight way in case not using mixins is acceptable for you. The first solution wraps up your approach:

#### A: Pass variable `require` or `fs` to your jade template

Make sure that the needed functions are available (scoped) during jade template parsing. Assuming you're using express this might look like this:

```
app.get('/', function(req,res) {
  res.render('portfolio.jade', {
    title: 'svg with jade test',
    fs: require('fs')
  })
});
```

Now your mixin should work with two minor modifications:

```
mixin svg(file)
  - var xml = fs.readFileSync(file)
  div!= xml
```

You can even just pass `{ require: 'require' }` as a local to the jade template and use your original mixin code. Note that in any case you have to suppress escaping the output with `!=` in order to transfer SVG markup so that it is interpreted and rendered instead of being displayed as (HTML) text. Also be aware that `fs` lives in your app/controller code and paths must be expressed relative to it, e.g.:

```
mixin('public/images/my-logo.svg')
```

#### B: Or just use include (without mixins)

Jade is capable of including other type of contents, so a simple

```
div
  include images/my-logo.svg
```

does this job as well. Unfortunately this doesn't work dynamically, so you cannot include files using passed variables within mixins. But: As long as you're not planning to enrich your mixin with additional logic, this solution doesn't even produce (way) more code.

Comment: You don't need `!=` in div in case B since you include file inside of div as a partial.

Comment: @user61382 Thanks for this correction, I finally fixed that!

Answer (score 1):

Above answers do work but if you want to do an SVG inline. You can do it like this.

```
//- Cover.
.ywp_title
    h1
        | Some text
        span
            | More Span Text
            svg.bg_svg(version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 430 100" style="enable-background:new 0 0 430 100;" xml:space="preserve")
                g(style="fill: #BADA55;")
                    path(style="fill: pink;" class="public-spaces-bg-fill" d="M356.2,60.1C356.2,60.1,356.2,60.1,356.2,60.1c0.1,0,0.1,0,0.2,0C356.3,60.1,356.3,60.1,356.2,60.1 M424.4,73.2c0-2.8-2-6.1-3.2-9.8c-2-5.8-4-11.7-6.3-17.5c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.5c0,0,0,0,0,0v0c-0.7-1.4-1.8-2.4-3.4-3.1 c-12-5.5-26.3-7.4-40.3-8.6c18,0.1,36,0.4,54,0.6c-0.6,0-4.5-13.4-4.9-14.3c-0.4-1-4.1-14.2-5.2-14.2C380.4,5.4,345.8,5,311.3,5.1 c-66.5,0.2-133.3,1.8-199.3,9.8c-20.8,2.5-41.7,5.4-62.2,9.6c-2.1,0.4-4.2,0.9-6.4,1.3l-17.7,4.4c-1.1,0.3-2.3,0.7-3.4,1.1 c-5.1,1.7-12.1,3.6-15.7,7.8c-1.2,1.4-1.7,2.8-1.2,4.6c0.3,1,0.7,2,1,3.1C13,71.7,18.1,75.5,20.1,76.6c7.7,4.1,16.4,6,25,7.5 c43.4,7.7,88,9.4,132.1,10.3c44.7,0.9,89.5,0.2,134.1-1.8c21.6-1,43.2-2.3,64.6-5c14.1-1.8,31.6-2.6,44.6-9.1 C423.3,76.9,424.4,75.2,424.4,73.2c0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.2C424.5,73.4,424.4,73.3,424.4,73.2")
        | and more text.
```

Comment: Not answering the original question, but it's what I needed. This works great with the results you can get from https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/server-side-rendering which allows you to use the built icons without installing any fontawesome stuff. Of course, should indicate where the icons came from and honor the license, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I have better luck with `object`, such as

```
  a.svg(href='/')
    object(type="image/svg+xml" data="/img/#{data.menu.img}.svg")
      | #{data.menu.title}
```

Comment: As a general solution for displaying svg's with scriptable content, this is what I do, but op is asking specifically about including the xml content in the jade output, so this doesn't really apply.