# How to create jade mixing for adding svg element on the page?

Tags: javascript, svg, pug

I need jade mixing to add existing svg icons on the page. I created such a code for that:

```
mixin svgicon(path, style)
      object(type="image/svg+xml" data=path style=style class="logo")
```

add svg to the page like this:

+svgicon("/svg/unstyled/facebook-logo-button.svg", "width:50px; height:50px")

The rendered code in the browser is as follows

[image]

but I cannot change color of the svg in this mixing. How can this mixing be recreated in order to add fill(color) to the svg?

Comment: You can pass in `fill` attribute similar to the way you are passing in width and height.

Comment: I cannot pass fill attribute to the object as object doesn't have fill

Comment: But I think you can pass in `fill` attribute as part of the `style`, because fill can be defined in css also https://css-tricks.com/cascading-svg-fill-color/

Comment: object doesn't accept fill css property

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23907512/include-svg-xml-in-jade-template